# If you own a portfolio of five stocks and want to diversify, which would you be least likely to recommend?

Tags: diversification

Gill, Madura. [*Personal Finance*, 4th Canadian Edition 2019](https://www.amazon.ca/Personal-Finance-Canadian-Pearson-Package/dp/013485201X/ref=pd_cp_14_1?pd_rd_w=c29n6&pf_rd_p=64a84aa4-b549-4445-9bf3-48bdeed5f24a&pf_rd_r=82BZKGBE1YW3BZXRTA41&pd_rd_r=ac94fdf8-0331-4f63-9fd4-08392967896d&pd_rd_wg=LkHyc&pd_rd_i=013485201X&psc=1&refRID=82BZKGBE1YW3BZXRTA41). p 323. Emboldenings are mine.

> 13. Lee Ann 
>       would like to diversify her individual stock with other investments. Currently, she owns a portfolio of five stocks. Which of the following investments would you be least likely to recommend to Lee Ann in order to help her achieve her 
>       goal?
>
> a. A bond
>   b. Real estate
>   c. An income trust
>   d. A stock-based mutual fund

I picked d, because Lee already "owns a portfolio of five stocks".

But the answer key on p 519 says b. Why?

Comment: Real answer: Because if the financial adviser recommends real estate, Lee Ann goes to a real estate broker to make her next investment and the financial adviser doesn't get any commission.

Comment: Answer keys make simple mistakes such as typos sometimes. Also that is just a terrible question. There is not enough information to answer properly.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it might have something to do with the amount of money concentrated in one spot.

With the others, Lee Ann can start with a small amount - the smallest purchasable parcel of bonds etc likely costs less than a cheap apartment. But property tends to come in big lumps - you can’t just buy a front gate today and slowly buy the rest of the house as you earn more money.

So if Lee Ann has $1000 in each of 5 stocks and then has to pay $100,000 for one piece of real estate, it’s not diversifying - it is concentrating her exposure into real estate. The original 5 stocks end up as a small fraction of her total portfolio.

Caveats:

1. This depends on the numbers. If Lee Ann had $100,000 in each of the 5 stocks, putting $100,000 into real estate sounds reasonable as diversification.
2. You can probably justify why any of the multiple-choice answers works as ‘the’ correct answer. I expect this is why investment advisors want to know so much about someone’s full financial picture before making recommendations.
3. This answer isn’t financial advice.

Comment: Of course, we need to know whether "Real estate" means *plop $100K on some rental property" or means *buy $1000 worth of shares in a REIT.

Comment: @RonJohn Yup. Sometimes exam question writers don’t reveal enough of their assumptions. Or maybe it just prepares students to face the whims and variety of clients. Advice that’s wrong for one client might also be wrong for another client, but for different reasons. If the advice is somehow deemed right, celebrate and try to keep the client. :P

Answer (score 0):

An income trust is a *container* for investments, **not a type** of investment.  The bottom line is that "income trust" is the correct answer to **a different question**.

I do think, though, that (d) is *also* an acceptable answer.

Comment: Sorry. Typo. I meant b.